# block IP address on MAC

Tags: macos, security, firewall

I am connected to a network and there is a particular node that keeps scanning me and attempting to connect to me.  It is always from the same IP.  I have looked and cant seem to find a way to block that IP on my MAC.  Is there a way to drop this particular IP on my MAC?

Comment: Is there no iptables on mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On current MacOSes you would want to use packet filtering: https://blog.neilsabol.site/post/quickly-easily-adding-pf-packet-filter-firewall-rules-macos-osx/